# My keyboard be turn off after a while

Tags: linux, usb, debian, keyboard

My keyboard was turned off after a while, and other USB devices still working, I try to connect to other USB ports and some times worked but it's happening again, and some time doesn't work, so I removed the other USB and, also restarted the system and the result is the same.
And sometimes when the system starts booting it is turned off and not working becomes turned off

This happens when the keyboard becomes tuned off:
[image: this happens when the keyboard becomes tuned off]

How to solve this issue?

OS: Debian 11

Comment: See if your OS supports USB power management . The USB port may be turning off to save power, but that is unusual for the keyboard. Make sure your USB keyboard has fresh batteries.

Comment: @John I removed my hard drive that os installed on that but my keyboard doesn't work , any my keyboard not wireless

Comment: The chain of events is not at all clear. It is looking like an OS problem.

Comment: Also try a different keyboard.